# Preventing SettingWithCopy warning, proper use of views/copies of Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Should I always explicitly generate a copy using the .copy() method when changing a dataframe created from a slice of another dataframe? Otherwise, I get a SettingWithCopy warning. However, in this case, it didn't lead to any trouble; the original dataframe is unchanged.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[6,3,2],[4,3,2],[5,4,2],[4,3,5]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  6  3  2
1  4  3  2
2  5  4  2
3  4  3  5
>>> df2 = df.loc[df.a<6, :]
>>> df2.loc[df2.b==3, 'b'] = 99
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:117: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
__main__:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  6  3  2
1  4  3  2
2  5  4  2
3  4  3  5
>>> df2
   a   b  c
1  4  99  2
2  5   4  2
3  4  99  5
```

Alternatively, if I do the following I get no warning.

```
>>> df2 = df.loc[df.a<6, :].copy()
>>> df2.loc[df2.b==3, 'b'] = 99
>>> df2
   a   b  c
1  4  99  2
2  5   4  2
3  4  99  5
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  6  3  2
1  4  3  2
2  5  4  2
3  4  3  5
```

Is the latter better? (And hence why I get no warning). In what sense? Is it because I am assured that df2 is a copy and therefore cannot alter the original dataframe df?

Comment: Did you make sure that these two options do exactly the same thing?

Comment: well `df2` gets `99` inserted in the right places for both implementations. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The SettingWithCopyWarning comes up if there exists ambiguity in how the command can be construed by the user. In the first case, it is clear to pandas that values should be assigned to `df2`. However, it is not clear if the user expects the value assignment to propagate into `df` itself, which is why the warning is raised. Internally, pandas tracks this using the `_is_copy` attribute for dataframes. When `df2` is created, the `_is_copy` attribute stores a weak reference to `df`.

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([[6,3,2],[4,3,2],[5,4,2],[4,3,5]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

In [3]: df2 = df.loc[df.a<6, :]

In [4]: df2._is_copy
Out[4]: <weakref at 0x7f0dae5a3770; to 'DataFrame' at 0x7f0daef08850>
```

In the second case, `df2` is explicitly created as a copy of `df`, so pandas does not store a weakref to `df`.

```py
In [5]: df2 = df.loc[df.a<6, :].copy()

In [6]: df2._is_copy

In [7]: print(df2._is_copy)
None
```

Whatever you do to `df2` is not expected to affect other dataframes, so there's no ambiguity in value assignment, and therefore, no need for the SettingWithCopyWarning to be raised.

Source:

- Pandas docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
- https://tnwei.github.io/posts/settings-with-copy-warning-pandas/